# Silently install crystal report with my application setup?

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, crystal-reports, installation

I am working in Visual studio 2013. C# 4.5 win-form application. I am using crystal reports from many years. But the problem is that, Crystal report does not installs silently with my application setup. I search lots of options, but there is no solution to install crystal report silently with my application.

Is there any way to install crystal report silently with my application setup ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a pre-requisite in your installation. The pre-requisites are xml based .prq files. The pre-requisite editor is where you can set the option to install it silently.

This will be based on the Crystal reports redistributable msi.The "one I created earlier" can be modified to send the silent flag (cmdline="/norestart" cmdlinesilent="/qn") for bootstrapping the crystal msi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <conditions>
        <condition Type="1" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CE26F10F-C80F-4377-908B-1B7882AE2CE3}" FileName="" ReturnValue=""></condition>
    </conditions>
    <files>
        <file LocalFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2011\Redist\0409\i386\CRRedist2008_x86.msi" URL="http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/downloads/redistributables/vs_2008/redist/x86/CRRedist2008_x86.msi" CheckSum="5C6DB57CEB6995BF44E1D273EA266AB1" FileSize="0,17960448"></file>
    </files>
    <execute file="CRRedist2008_x86.msi" cmdline="/norestart" cmdlinesilent="/qn" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1"></execute>
    <properties Id="CRRedist2008_x86" Description="This installs Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 x86 Redistributable Package (32 bit)."></properties>
    <behavior Optional="1"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I will mark it as answer after i will test it.